# How to replace string in a specific line using sed command or awk

Tags: awk, sed

I have a text file and it has the following contents

```
    #                                       
    #   Keywords:                                   
    #                                                                           
    LiFePO4                                     
    end                                     
    name    Li5FeO4                                 
    cell                                        
        18.557309   18.316802   9.125725    90.047539   90.100646   90.060551 0 0 0 0 0 0           
    fractional  1                                   
    Li  core    0.06001     0.059408    0.849507    1   1   0   0   0   0
    Li1 core    0.025416    0.339078    0.128746    1   1   0   0   0   0
    Li2 core    0.02517     0.838929    0.130747    1   1   0   0   0   0
    Li3 core    0.525498    0.339179    0.127632    1   1   0   0   0   0
    Li4 core    0.524753    0.841333    0.129329    1   1   0   0   0   0
    Li5 core    0.179907    0.158182    0.634012    1   1   0   0   0   0
    Li6 core    0.180817    0.666028    0.628327    1   1   0   0   0   0
```

This is the input that I need to supply to a tool which used in some research application. Now I need to replace the `0` on the first line which starts with `Li` on the third column from the last. That is, there are four zeros towards the end in each of the lines starting with `Li`. I need to replace the second zero and so the file will have the the contents as follows:

```
    #                                       
    #   Keywords:                                   
    #                                                                           
    LiFePO4                                     
    end                                     
    name    Li5FeO4                                 
    cell                                        
        18.557309   18.316802   9.125725    90.047539   90.100646   90.060551 0 0 0 0 0 0           
    fractional  1                                   
    Li  core    0.06001     0.059408    0.849507    1   1   0   1   0   0
    Li1 core    0.025416    0.339078    0.128746    1   1   0   0   0   0
    Li2 core    0.02517     0.838929    0.130747    1   1   0   0   0   0
    Li3 core    0.525498    0.339179    0.127632    1   1   0   0   0   0
    Li4 core    0.524753    0.841333    0.129329    1   1   0   0   0   0
    Li5 core    0.179907    0.158182    0.634012    1   1   0   0   0   0
    Li6 core    0.180817    0.666028    0.628327    1   1   0   0   0   0
```

I am planning to use this in a shell script so that I can supply the modified file as an input to another program and use it's out put for further processing.

I have tried the following code, but it is not working

`sed -E "s/^(([^ ]+ +){3})0  /\1 /" file1`

Answer (score 2):

You may try this `sed`:

```sh
sed -E '/^[[:blank:]]*Li /s/0(([[:blank:]]+[[:digit:]]+){2})$/1\1/' file.txt

#
#   Keywords:
#
LiFePO4
end
name    Li5FeO4
cell
18.557309   18.316802   9.125725    90.047539   90.100646   90.060551 0 0 0 0 0 0
fractional  1
Li  core    0.06001     0.059408    0.849507    1   1   0   1   0   0
Li1 core    0.025416    0.339078    0.128746    1   1   0   0   0   0
Li2 core    0.02517     0.838929    0.130747    1   1   0   0   0   0
Li3 core    0.525498    0.339179    0.127632    1   1   0   0   0   0
Li4 core    0.524753    0.841333    0.129329    1   1   0   0   0   0
Li5 core    0.179907    0.158182    0.634012    1   1   0   0   0   0
Li6 core    0.180817    0.666028    0.628327    1   1   0   0   0   0
```

**Explanation:**

- `^[[:blank:]]*Li /`: Match a line starting with `"Li "` (allows optional whitespaces at the start)
- `s`: substitute command
- `/0(([[:blank:]]+[[:digit:]]+){2})$/`: Match `0` followed by 2 numeric fields before end and match it in capture group #1
- `1\1`: Replace with `1` followed by back-reference of group #1

---

An equivalent `gnu awk` command:

```sh
awk '!done && $1 ~ /^Li/ && NF > 3 {
   $0 = gensub(/^(.+[[:blank:]])0(([[:blank:]]+[[:digit:]]+){2})$/, "\\11\\2", "1")
   done = 1
} 1' file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '$1=="Li"{sub(/0   0   0$/,"1   0   0")} 1' file
    #
    #   Keywords:
    #
    LiFePO4
    end
    name    Li5FeO4
    cell
        18.557309   18.316802   9.125725    90.047539   90.100646   90.060551 0 0 0 0 0 0
    fractional  1
    Li  core    0.06001     0.059408    0.849507    1   1   0   1   0   0
    Li1 core    0.025416    0.339078    0.128746    1   1   0   0   0   0
    Li2 core    0.02517     0.838929    0.130747    1   1   0   0   0   0
    Li3 core    0.525498    0.339179    0.127632    1   1   0   0   0   0
    Li4 core    0.524753    0.841333    0.129329    1   1   0   0   0   0
    Li5 core    0.179907    0.158182    0.634012    1   1   0   0   0   0
    Li6 core    0.180817    0.666028    0.628327    1   1   0   0   0   0
```